# Does using a HTTPS-enabled CDN provide full HTTPS security?

Tags: http, https, cdn

Apologies if this is a misguided question but the backend is not my strong point.

I am running a Wordpress website on a server which doesn't use HTTPS.

If I use a CDN like Cloudflare or Netlify to serve my content, it will do so over HTTPS.

However a CDN will be fetching data occasionally from the original server itself, which will still be in HTTP.

So in this scenario, is it not the case that despite having HTTPS showing in the browser, it gives a false sense of security because some data is still being sent over HTTP to and from the source? For example, if I log in to the Wordpress site, won't that involve communication to the HTTP source server, therefore exposing my credentials, even though the browser 'thinks' the connection is HTTPS?

More generally, just because HTTPS shows up on the frontend, doesn't that mean that somewhere on the backend, data could still be transferred over HTTP?

Answer (score 2):

> More generally, just because HTTPS shows up on the frontend, doesn't that mean that somewhere on the backend, data could still be transferred over HTTP?

Unfortunately yes, that's exactly what happens. This configuration is insecure. If an attacker gets to MITM the CDN-origin connection they can tamper with the website's contents, even if the end user sees HTTPS in their browser.

CDNs do allow you to set up HTTPS on the CDN-origin connection, which would make the website completely secure. I highly recommend everyone to do that.

The only reason CDNs support HTTP origins (and even encourage you to use them in tutorials and docs) is to make set up easier for devs. They want you to have the least pain possible when integrating their services, at the cost of security.